# How can I find the average of each similar entry in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this list of tuples

```
[('Jem', 10), ('Sam', 10), ('Sam', 2), ('Jem', 9), ('Jem', 10)]
```

How do I find the average of the numbers coupled with each name, i.e. the average of all the numbers stored in a tuple with Jem, and then output them? In this example, the output would be:

```
Jem 9.66666666667
Sam 6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this. One is easy, one is pretty.

#### Easy:

Use a dictionary! It's easy to build a `for` loop that goes through your tuples and appends the second element to a dictionary, keyed on the first element.

```
d = {}
tuples = [('Jem', 10), ('Sam', 10), ('Sam', 2), ('Jem', 9), ('Jem', 10)]
for tuple in tuples:
    key,val = tuple
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
```

Once it's in a dictionary, you can do:

```
for name, values in d.items():
    print("{name} {avg}".format(name=name, avg=sum(values)/len(values)))
```

#### Pretty:

Use `itertools.groupby`. This only works if your data is sorted by the key you want to group by (in this case, `t[0]` for each `t` in `tuples`) so it's not ideal in this case, but it's a nice way to highlight the function.

```
from itertools import groupby

tuples = [('Jem', 10), ('Sam', 10), ('Sam', 2), ('Jem', 9), ('Jem', 10)]
tuples.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])
# tuples is now [('Jem', 10), ('Jem', 9), ('Jem', 10), ('Sam', 10), ('Sam', 2)]

groups = groupby(tuples, lambda tup: tup[0])
```

This builds a structure that looks kind of like:

```
[('Jem', [('Jem', 10), ('Jem', 9), ('Jem', 10)]),
 ('Sam', [('Sam', 10), ('Sam', 2)])]
```

We can use that to build our names and averages:

```
for groupname, grouptuples in groups:
    values = [t[1] for t in groupvalues]
    print("{name} {avg}".format(name=groupname, avg=sum(values)/len(values)))
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you used `key=lambda tup: tup[0]` for sorting?

Comment: @Finn In this specific case, that is unnecessary as the `tuple` would sort by the first element by default. But I guess they left it in there to handle the general case if you wanted to sort by some other element.

Comment: *Explicit is better than implicit.* No other reason -- I'm aware that tuples sort this way naturally, but it does more-cleanly highlight the parallels between sorting a sequence and grouping that sequence by a constituent element of that sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a straight-forward case for `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [('Jem', 10), ('Sam', 10), ('Sam', 2), ('Jem', 9), ('Jem', 10)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in l:
    d[key].append(value)
```

Then calculating the mean

```
from numpy import mean
for key in d:
    print(key, mean(d[key]))
```

Output

```
Jem 9.66666666667
Sam 6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use List comprehensions:

```
l = [('Jem', 10), ('Sam', 10), ('Sam', 2), ('Jem', 9), ('Jem', 10)]

def avg(l):
    return sum(l)/len(l)

result = [(n, avg([v[1] for v in l if v[0] is n])) for n in set([n[0] for n in l])]
# result is [('Jem', 9.666666666666666), ('Sam', 6.0)]
```

Comment: `from collections import defaultdict;d=defaultdict(list);map(lambda k,v: d[k].append(v),l);[(k,sum(v)/len(v)) for k,v in d.items()]` one-liners aren't always best :)

Comment: @AdamSmith so how to write a list comprehension in separate lines?

Comment: You don't, that's my point! :) I think this situation is poorly suited to a list comp. That said, I just noticed you should be doing `if v[0] == n` not `if v[0] is n`. You're comparing equality not identity!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I thought if the object which i am testing against is immutable using identity is the better solution?

Comment: Two immutable objects may not have the same identity. Python MIGHT cache the object and re-use it, but that's an implementation concern. `a = 10e12; b = 10e12; a is b` wil fail while `c = 1; d = 1; c is d` will succeed.